# Popup for suspending from suggested edits contains encoded symbols

Tags: bug, status-review, suggested-edits, moderator-tools, html-entities

The native browser confirmation popup that appears when a moderator is attempting to suspend a user from suggest edits contains encoded symbols in the username. Moreover, if the Cancel button is clicked, then a second popup appears, but with correctly displayed username.

> [image]